# Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable while trying to create multiple task and run them in parallel

Tags: c#, task

I am trying to create multiple C# task and run them all in parallel.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task1 = await WriteDouble();
        var task2 = await WriteString();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    }

    private static async Task WriteString()
    {
        await using var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\test1.txt");
        await file.WriteLineAsync("this is string");
    }

    private static async Task WriteDouble()
    {
        await using var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\test2.txt");
        await file.WriteLineAsync("this is double");
    }
}
```

Here `WriteDouble` and `WriteString` doing file writes task, what is best Task return type here?

Currently I am getting below compile error,

> Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable

Comment: apart from the async-await consideration (i.e. when you should be awaiting tasks), you should consider the difference with the terms concurrent and parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable names (and the use of `Task.WhenAll`) suggest you're expecting to store tasks in them - but you're *awaiting* the tasks returned by those methods. Just remove the `await` operator:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var task1 = WriteDouble();
    var task2 = WriteString();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Basically you need to differentiate between "the tasks returned by asynchronous methods" and "the result of a task"... only use `await` when you want to get the result of a task, which you don't in this case in the first two lines of `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

**Task.WhenAll(...)** has several overloads. The reason there is a compilation error is because the overload method expects all tasks to return the same type.

```
//This will work only if all tasks return the same type
var results = await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);
```

If the tasks result types are different, you could do something like this:

```
double t1Result;
var t1 = WriteDouble().ContinueWith(d => t1Result = d.Result);
string t2Result = string. Empty;
var t2 = WriteString().ContinueWith(s => t2Result = s.Result);
//because the tasks return different types, the WhenAll overload
//returns a Task (void) and can't be assigned to a variable   
await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2)

Console.WriteLine(t1Result);    
Console.WriteLine(t2Result);
```

Comment: *`var t1Result`* -- This won't compile.

Comment: right. It was pseudo-code. Replace "var" with the appropriate type and that should work. I just made the edit.